# How do I use cffile action= read the right way?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cffile

I have a table with my directory folder which contains all of my .txt files. Now I want that all .txt files are readable.  I know I have to use `<cffile action="read" ...>`, but always something went wrong. How do I integrate the `cffile` tag into my script?

```
<cfparam name="name" default="0">

<h3>cfdirectory-Test</h3>

<cfdirectory  
    directory = "#ExpandPath('150903T')#"
    action= "list"
    name = "meinVerzeichnis" 
    sort = "name ASC, Type DESC, dateLastModified, Size"  
    type = "all"
    filter = "*#name#*"
    >

<cftable border="2"
  query="meinVerzeichnis" 
  htmltable 
  colheaders> 
<cfcol 
 header="Name:" 
 text="#Name#"> 
<cfcol  
  header="Type:" 
  text="#Type#"> 
<cfcol 
 header="Gr&ouml;&szlig;e:" 
 text="#Size#">
<cfcol 
 header="Letztes Modifikationsdatum:" 
 text="#dateLastModified#">

</cftable> 

<form method="get" action="msuche.cfm">
    <button type="submit">Zur&uuml;ck</button>
</form>
```

Comment: *Now I want that all .txt files are readable.* What do you mean by "readable"?  Phrases like *something went wrong*  are very ambiguous. Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32967803/edit) with the full error message and the actual code which caused it.

Comment: To add to Leigh's comment...please provide what was expected/wanted and what actually happened.